# Triggering Select2:Select instead of change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

The `select2:select` event gives you data about the selected object. `change` event does not. Hence for initializing my selects:

```
async function initSelect(jobj, getDataParams, width, callback) {
try {
    if (jobj.data('select2Id') || jobj.data('select2')) {
        jobj.select2('destroy').empty()
    }
} catch (e){}

try {

    if(callback) {
        jobj.on('select2:select', function (e) {
            callback(e)
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I have dependent selects, for example, if you select SelectA, SelectB gets initialized. I would like to be able to programmatically select an element in SelectA, and for it to trigger its `select2:select` event which would then destroy and repopulate SelectB.

Currently all the answers I've seen on the internet say to `$('#selectA').val(301235).trigger('change')` but that does not cause SelectA's `select2:select` event and so I can't execute the callback that knows selectA's data to use to populate SelectB.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like instead of trying to grab the data from the event, like which was provided to me in `select2:select`, but not `change`, just obtain the data from the currently selected item in the callback:

```
if(callback) {
    jobj.on('change', function (e) {
        // var data = jobj.select2('data')[0]);
        callback(e)
    });
}
```